# Parsley Range validation error message issue

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I have a field to which I am setting the range validation dynamically from 70.00 to 1050.00 which works fine as shown below

[image]

The issue is when the field is validated it shows the error message **ignoring the decimal points**

[image]

I want the error message to say "**This value should be between 70.00 to 1050.00.**" I tried searching and doing some changes to my code but it didn't help.

Can someone point me on how to get this done?

**Side Note:** It works if decimal places has other values in it like "70.01 to 1050.01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I added a attribute at runtime 
**`"data-parsley-range-message"`** 
and added my error text to it which did the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right, `parlsey` converts them to float, then back to string. I'm not sure how simple it would be to change this, but I'm wouldn't be opposed to a PR. Or customize the error message.